# PDO MVC Echoing data from database to page

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, pdo

I'm not new to PHP, but I am new to all this PDO and MVC stuff. I'm basically trying to echo out data from the database to the page.

**Model (_dashboard.php)**

```
<?php

require_once('_connection.php');

class ConnectToDB {
    private $db;

    public function  __construct(){
        $this->db =new connection();
        $this->db = $this->db->dbConnection(); //uses the connection in connection class
    }

    public function teachersStudents($id){
        // this function checks whether the user name exists and if its a match
        if(!empty($id)){
            $st = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM students WHERE id=?");
            $st->bindParam(1, $id);
            $st->execute();

            if ($st->rowCount() == 1) {
                $result = $st->fetchAll();
                foreach($result as $row){
                     echo "<tr>";
                     echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
                     echo "</tr>";
                 }
            } 
        } 
    }

}  

 // Close database connection
 $dbh = null; 

 ?>
```

**View (dashboard.phtml)**

```
<?php

    require_once('_dashboard.php');

    $object = new ConnectToDB();
    $object->teachersStudents($id); 

    echo $result; 
?>
```

Result

> Notice: Undefined variable: result

I'm probably doing this completely wrong so a push in the right direction would be appreciated. Here's the controller but really has nothing to do with it.

**Controller**

```
<?php

    $view = new stdClass();
    $view->pageTitle = 'Dashboard';
    require_once('views/dashboard.phtml');
```

Comment: How do you pass `$result` from model to view?

Comment: There is a require_once i forgot to copy from the code, code updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$result` is undefined Change your function to return the result.

```
$result = $st->fetchAll();
return $result;
```

Then move your code to display HTML in the view instead:

```
require_once('_dashboard.php');

$object = new ConnectToDB();
$result = $object->teachersStudents($id); 

foreach($result as $row){
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Getting this on the page 'Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()'

Comment: @CarlR did you modify your function like above? also do `var_dump($result);` to see the content of your array

Comment: `var_dump($result);` is giving `NULL`

Comment: Fixed it, i have a if condition i used in a login function i didn't remove when i copied the code, thanks :)